# How to use libsvm in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, kernel, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am new to matlab and don't know how to use libsvm. Is there any sample code for classifying some data (with 2 features) with a SVM and then visualize the result? How about with kernel (RBF, Polynomial, and Sigmoid )?
I saw that readme file in libsvm package, but I could not make a head or tail of it would you please give an example of classification of 2 classes using Support Vector Machines (SVM) in matlab something like:

```
Attribute_1    Attribute_2   Class
170            66            -1
160            50            -1
170            63            -1
173            61            -1
168            58            -1
184            88            +1
189            94            +1
185            88            +1
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Are you using libsvm from here: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/?

Comment: yes, I've also seen the guide there but could not use it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In libsvm package, in the file matlab/README, you can find the following examples:

```
Examples
========

Train and test on the provided data heart_scale:

matlab> [heart_scale_label, heart_scale_inst] = libsvmread('../heart_scale');
matlab> model = svmtrain(heart_scale_label, heart_scale_inst, '-c 1 -g 0.07');
matlab> [predict_label, accuracy, dec_values] = svmpredict(heart_scale_label, heart_scale_inst, model); % test the training data

For probability estimates, you need '-b 1' for training and testing:

matlab> [heart_scale_label, heart_scale_inst] = libsvmread('../heart_scale');
matlab> model = svmtrain(heart_scale_label, heart_scale_inst, '-c 1 -g 0.07 -b 1');
matlab> [heart_scale_label, heart_scale_inst] = libsvmread('../heart_scale');
matlab> [predict_label, accuracy, prob_estimates] = svmpredict(heart_scale_label, heart_scale_inst, model, '-b 1');

To use precomputed kernel, you must include sample serial number as
the first column of the training and testing data (assume your kernel
matrix is K, # of instances is n):

matlab> K1 = [(1:n)', K]; % include sample serial number as first column
matlab> model = svmtrain(label_vector, K1, '-t 4');
matlab> [predict_label, accuracy, dec_values] = svmpredict(label_vector, K1, model); % test the training data

We give the following detailed example by splitting heart_scale into
150 training and 120 testing data.  Constructing a linear kernel
matrix and then using the precomputed kernel gives exactly the same
testing error as using the LIBSVM built-in linear kernel.

matlab> [heart_scale_label, heart_scale_inst] = libsvmread('../heart_scale');
matlab>
matlab> % Split Data
matlab> train_data = heart_scale_inst(1:150,:);
matlab> train_label = heart_scale_label(1:150,:);
matlab> test_data = heart_scale_inst(151:270,:);
matlab> test_label = heart_scale_label(151:270,:);
matlab>
matlab> % Linear Kernel
matlab> model_linear = svmtrain(train_label, train_data, '-t 0');
matlab> [predict_label_L, accuracy_L, dec_values_L] = svmpredict(test_label, test_data, model_linear);
matlab>
matlab> % Precomputed Kernel
matlab> model_precomputed = svmtrain(train_label, [(1:150)', train_data*train_data'], '-t 4');
matlab> [predict_label_P, accuracy_P, dec_values_P] = svmpredict(test_label, [(1:120)', test_data*train_data'], model_precomputed);
matlab>
matlab> accuracy_L % Display the accuracy using linear kernel
matlab> accuracy_P % Display the accuracy using precomputed kernel

Note that for testing, you can put anything in the
testing_label_vector.  For more details of precomputed kernels, please
read the section ``Precomputed Kernels'' in the README of the LIBSVM
package.
```

Comment: I know this thread is old, but what is meant by "sample serial number" in regards to the precomputed kernel?

Comment: They are referring to `(1:n)'`. Basically, you could provide the kernel in a different order than your samples are. Otherwise, just use `(1:n)'`