# Matlab SVM for getting output in binary form

Tags: image, matlab, svm, biometrics

I need to use SVM for image features extracted. The ouput of SVM should be in binary. Please share the resources if any available. Actually I am working on sclera detection. I manually got the sclera region from the training images and have the features extracted in the form of histogram values of each and every sub region in the image. Now I will extract the same features from the test image. Upon receiving the features from the test image, I need to compare test and training features with SVM on whether that particular block corresponds to sclera or not. If i get an out put in 0 and 1 form, then I shall use the code to segmentation of the region in an easier way.

Comment: You may need to expand on this question to get a good answer. Try including what you have tried and some more information about your project.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) for Matlab, which is probably the most widely used free SVM toolbox in Matlab.

There is a useful post about libsvm in Matlab [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556410/how-to-use-libsvm-in-matlab). When you download libsvm, it contains several examples for Matlab that I was able to run in a few minutes. You can easily modify one of those examples to get your binary output.