# LIBSVM in MATLAB/Octave - what's the output of libsvmread?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

The second output of the `libsvmread` command is a set of features for each given training example.

For example, in the following MATLAB command:

```
[heart_scale_label, heart_scale_inst] = libsvmread('../heart_scale');
```

This second variable (heart_scale_inst) holds content in a form that I don't understand, for example:

```
<1, 1> -> 0.70833
```

What is the meaning of it? How is it to be used (I can't plot it, the way it is)?

PS. If anyone could please recommend a good LIBSVM tutorial, I'd appreciate it. I haven't found anything useful and the README file isn't very clear... Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a `sparse` matrix.  Type `whos heart_scale_label heart_scale_inst` to see.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use libsvm in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556410/how-to-use-libsvm-in-matlab)

Comment: Thanks @chappjc. I've seen the link you mentioned before I posted my question; actually, I tried implementing the answer given to that question and that's where I'm stuck :( So what does the sparse matrix represent? Which part is the features and what is the rest...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definitive tutorial for LIBSVM for beginners is called: [A Practical Guide to SVM Classification](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf) it is available from the site of the authors of LIBSVM.

The second parameter returned is called the instance matrix. It is a matrix, let call it M, M(1,:) are the features of data point 1 and so on. The matrix is sparse that is why it prints out weirdly. If you want to see it fully print full(M).

```
[heart_scale_label, heart_scale_inst] = libsvmread('../heart_scale');
```

with heart_scale_label and heart_scale_inst you should be able to train an SVM by issuing:

```
mod = svmtrain(heart_scale_label,heart_scale_inst,'-c 1 -t 0');
```

I strong suggest you read the above linked guide to learn how to set the c parameter (and possibly, in case of RBF kernel the gamma parameter), but the above line is how you would train with that data.

Comment: Thanks @carlosdc! It's so weird that it's a sparse matrix, there are hardly any zeros inside... I was confused because I wasn't even able to plot the matrix (as a graph) - but OK, now I see that plotting sparse matrices in octave isn't straightforward... so thanks again! :)

Answer (score -1):

I think it is the probability with which test case has been predicted to heart_scale label category

Comment: Thanks @MohitJain but libsvmread was performed before I even trained the data... how could it predict the labels already?

Comment: Sorry didn't see that before!!